# Clearing data in SqlDataAdapter

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql-server, webforms

I'm using SQLDataAdapter to populate data from my SQL server database in 2 DropDownLists. Depending on what is selected in the first dropdown, the corresponding data is populated in the second. It works fine but data that has since been deleted by the admin on their side of the application and is no longer in the database is still showing up in the dropdowns.

Is there a way in which I can reset or clear what is already in the DataAdapter, refresh it and then show only the current data?

If it helps here is how I have the data binding to the dropdowns. Firstly a  general method which is called on page load to populate the first dropdown, and again in the _SelectedIndexChanged of the first dropdown to bind the relevant data to the second.

```html
 if (!IsPostBack)
        {
            DataBind();
            string query = "select Distinct ClubID, ClubName from Pitch";
            BindDropDownList(DDLClub, query, "ClubName", "ClubID", "Select Club");
            DDLPitches.Enabled = false;
            DDLPitches.Items.Insert(0, new ListItem("Select Pitch", "0"));
        }
```

```html
 private void BindDropDownList(DropDownList DDL, string query, string text, string value, string defaultText)
    {
        string ConnString = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["ConnString"].ConnectionString;
        SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(query);
        using (SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(ConnString))
        {
            using (SqlDataAdapter sda = new SqlDataAdapter())
            {
                cmd.Connection = con;
                con.Open();
                DDL.DataSource = cmd.ExecuteReader();
                DDL.DataTextField = text;
                DDL.DataValueField = value;
                DDL.DataBind();
                sda.Dispose();
                con.Close();
            }
        }
        DDL.Items.Insert(0, new ListItem(defaultText, "0"));
    }
```

```html
 protected void DDLClub_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        DDLPitches.Enabled = false;
        DDLPitches.Items.Clear();
        DDLPitches.Items.Insert(0, new ListItem("Select Pitch", "0"));
        int ClubID = int.Parse(DDLClub.SelectedItem.Value);
        if (ClubID > 0)
        {
            string query = string.Format("select PitchID, ClubID, ClubName, PitchName from Pitch where ClubID = {0}", ClubID);
            BindDropDownList(DDLPitches, query, "PitchName", "PitchID", "Select Pitch");
            DDLPitches.Enabled = true;
        }
    }
```

Comment: It is the ViewState that keeps the items in the DDL, not the adapter. I'm not sure what you mean by "since deleted". But after you delete somehting you have to rebind the new data to the DDL.

Comment: By 'since been deleted' I mean the admin has deleted the data on the admin side of the application manually and its no longer present in the database. Edited above also

Comment: Then make sure that after the code that deletes something that `BindDropDownList` is also executed.

Comment: Found the issue, I (stupidly) had old values in the second table which were once a foreign key to the records that the admin deleted and so were populating the first dropdown. Thanks for the help @VDWWD